# Aggregate/GroupBy with Distinct to concatenate values instead of counting

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop, vega, deneb

I've created a deneb visual where I have a summary aggregation that sums durations by status color. I would like to join/concatenate the statusses belonging to the same color to show as tooltip in the visual.

Given an example dataset of:

| Color | Status | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| red | Pause | 120 |
| red | Offline | 30 |
| green | Busy | 41 |
| blue | Waiting | 32 |
| blue | WrapUp | 230 |
| blue | Call | 321 |

I would like to do an aggregate like this:

| Color | Status | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| red | Pause, Offline | 150 |
| green | Busy | 41 |
| blue | Waiting, WrapUp, Call | 583 |

There is a join expression (join(array[, separator]) ≥ 5.3) that I thought could help me out here but according to the docs its >5.3. I cannot seem to get that expression to work with my dataset apart from using literal values:

`join([1,2,3], ',')`

I have the impression I'm looking over something obvious here as this shouldn't be too difficult of a transform. Any ideas?

Keep in mind this is Vega not Vega-Lite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {"Color": "red", "Status": "Pause", "Duration": 120},
        {"Color": "red", "Status": "Offline", "Duration": 30},
        {"Color": "green", "Status": "Busy", "Duration": 41},
        {"Color": "blue", "Status": "Waiting", "Duration": 32},
        {"Color": "blue", "Status": "WrapUp", "Duration": 230},
        {"Color": "blue", "Status": "Call", "Duration": 321}
      ],
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "aggregate",
          "groupby":["Color"],
          "fields": ["Status", "Duration"],
          "ops": ["values", "sum"],
          "as": ["Status", "Duration"]
        },
        {"type": "formula", "as": "Status", "expr": "pluck(datum.Status, 'Status')"}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hey Davide, thank you! I had to add a window+filter to get only the distinct values but the values op and the pluck expression gave me enough pointers to solve it myself. Also big thanks for your deneb examples! I am actually working on a adaptation of your gantt chart into a timeline visual.

Comment: Nice - I'll be keen to see how it turns out. Madison has some excellent timeline visuals that may also help you: https://www.linkedin.com/in/madison-giammaria-58463b33/

Comment: If you're interested, I wrote a small article for my visual [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/custom-deneb-visual-timeline-series-data-jaap-vennik-hkcsf/).

Answer (score 1):

Added a window+filter transform to get only unique values:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {"Color": "red", "Status": "Pause", "Duration": 120},
        {"Color": "red", "Status": "Offline", "Duration": 30},
        {"Color": "green", "Status": "Busy", "Duration": 41},
        {"Color": "blue", "Status": "Waiting", "Duration": 32},
        {"Color": "blue", "Status": "Waiting", "Duration": 62},
        {"Color": "blue", "Status": "Waiting", "Duration":42},
        {"Color": "blue", "Status": "WrapUp", "Duration": 230},
        {"Color": "blue", "Status": "Call", "Duration": 321}
      ],
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "window",
          "sort": {
            "field": [
              "Status"
            ],
            "order": [
              "ascending"
            ]
          },
          "ops": ["row_number"],
          "as": ["rownr"],
          "groupby": ["Status"]
        },
        {
          "type": "filter",
          "expr": "datum.rownr == 1"
        },
        {
          "type": "aggregate",
          "groupby": ["Color"],
          "fields": ["Status"],
          "ops": ["values"],
          "as": ["Status"]         
        },
        {"type": "formula", "as": "Status", "expr": "pluck(datum.Status, 'Status')"}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```